# Hide button if url is undefined

Tags: jquery, button, hide

I would like to hide a `url` button if the value is undefined. I passed an attribute and I added to a class.

```
<script="text/javascript">
.........
 j('.url').attr('href',ContextPath + home);

</script>
```

and the button is defined like

```
<a href="#header" class="btn btn-black txt-white url" title="button">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

I would like to hide the button if url is undefined. I wrote this jquery code but it doesn´t work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery (document).ready(function($) {

    $('url').children('a').each(function() {
        if(($(this).attr('url')=='undefined'))
        $(this).hide();
    })
})  
 </script>
```

if you press the button you send to the url http:/www.home/pagenull and I would like the button to hide and not send you to the url http:/www.home/pagenull and show the button if the url is not http:/www.home/pagenull. I've tried the answers and they don't work
Any idea?

Comment: There are no `a` children of elements in the class `url` (or url tags) in the HTML example, so what are you trying to target with `$('url').children('a').each(`...  ?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect.

---

**Change:**

```
<script="text/javascript">
.........
 j('.url').attr('href',ContextPath + home);

</script>
```

**to:**

```
<script="text/javascript">
 $('.url').attr('href',ContextPath + home);
</script>
```

Here were some issues:

- `j('.url')` is not valid jQuery; from > `j('.url')` to > `$('.url')`
- Those periods: `.........` could be causing issues.

---

**Change:**

```
jQuery (document).ready(function($) {

    $('url').children('a').each(function() {
        if(($(this).attr('url')=='undefined'))
        $(this).hide();
    })
})
```

**to:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.url').each(function() {
        if( $(this).attr('href') == undefined )
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Here were some issues:

- forgot '.' in front of class selector; from > `$('url') to >`$('.url')
- `.attr('url')` was not a valid attribute of `$(this)`; from > `.attr('url')` to > `.attr('href')`
- 'undefined' should not be a string; from > 'undefined' to > undefined
- missing ending ';' ~ makes code easier to read.
- `.each` operator was not targeting correct element; from > `$('url').children('a').each` to > `$('url').each`

Comment: Also, the each iterator does not appear to be targeting valid elements...at least, according to the HTML snippet the OP provided.  The `a` element has the class `url` and does not have child `a` elements

Answer (score 1):

I would do the same as Soulete, but I would add a line to reference the element to a variable during the loop iteration. Then I would create a decision structure with more testing.

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".url").each(function () {
            var r = $(this).attr('href')

            if (r === undefined || r === '#') {
                $(this).hide()
            }

        })
    })
</script>
```